# Transform time in JSON into actual time played PHP

Tags: javascript, php, time

Im working on a app, and I requested the time played for a whole game, from when they bought it, till now for a particular user, and this is the result I got in JSON.

```
{ 
  "TotalTimePlayed": "PT48M26.4570633S"
}
```

I need to transform that into: **Month, Day, Hours, Minutes, Seconds**

In my view, this is how my variable is displayed:

```
{{ $TotalTimePlayed }}
```

How would I transform that into readable time?

/********** EDIT ****************/

I inserted prettyDate function from helpers file, but that show wrong time though

```
{{ prettyDate($TotalTimePlayed) }}
```

In helper.php file:

```
function prettyDate($date) {
    return date("d h, I", strtotime($date));
}
```

/***** EDIT ******/

I would want it to like like this for eaxample:
**1M, 22D, 6H, 45M, 56S**

Comment: You expect people to play a single game session of .... months?

Comment: At least try something. Anything...

Comment: Google "JavaScript time object"

Comment: Could you create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that we could work with? That will make it more likely you'll get a high quality answer to your question.

Comment: when I say time played in a game, I meant not one game session, I meant the whole game when they started playing the game until now.

Comment: First tell us what that corresponds to in months, days, etc. Is it 48 minutes or months? Is 4570633 the number of seconds, and how does that relate to the 48 and 26?

Comment: And I tried this, look in the edit above. But it didnt give me the correct output:

Comment: I dont know what it corresponds to. I was hoping you guys knew?

Comment: What will the JSON text look like when a user has played some months, days, hours, ... seconds. We need the full format.

Comment: Look above, I edited my question

Comment: What game is this for?

Comment: This is for Halo 5. Im using the Halo 5 API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That duration format is in [ISO 8601 format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations).

You could proceed like this:

#### 1. Using DateInterval

The given format is almost the one expected by PHP's [DateInterval class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php), except that it does not allow fractional numbers.

So, we could first remove that fractional part, and then make use of this class to generate the output:

```
$json = '{ 
  "TotalTimePlayed": "PT48M26.4570633S"
}';

// Interpret JSON 
$obj = json_decode($json);

// Get value, and strip fractional part (not supported by DateInterval)
$value = preg_replace("/\.\d+/", "", $obj->TotalTimePlayed);

// Turn this into a DateInterval instance
$interval = new DateInterval($value);

// Use format method to get the desired output
echo $interval->format('%m months, %d days, %h hours, %i minutes, %s seconds');
```

Output for the example data would be:

> 0 months, 0 days, 0 hours, 48 minutes, 26 seconds

#### 2. Extracting the numbers with preg_match_all

This alternative does not make use of `DateInterval`, and thus can deal with the fractional seconds:

```
// Sample data:
$json = '{ 
  "TotalTimePlayed": "PT48M26.4570633S"
}';

// Interpret JSON 
$obj = json_decode($json);

// Extract all numbers in that "PT" format into an array
preg_match_all("/[\d.]+/", $obj->TotalTimePlayed, $parts);

// Convert string representations to numbers
$parts = array_map('floatval', $parts[0]);

// Pad the array on the left in order to get 5 elements (months, days, hours, minutes, seconds)
$parts = array_pad($parts, -5, 0);

// Output (just for checking)
echo json_encode($parts);
```

Outputs:

> [0,0,0,48,26.4570633]

If you don't want the fractional part of the seconds, then replace `'floatval'` by `'intval'` in the above code:

```
$parts = array_map('intval', $parts[0]);
```

Then the example will have as output:

> [0,0,0,48,26]

Then you could do something like this:

```
$playtime = $parts[0] . " months, " .
            $parts[1] . " days, " .
            $parts[2] . " hours, " .
            $parts[3] . " minutes, and " .
            $parts[4] . " seconds";
```

Comment: Ok, Thanks for the input I will see What I can do